# Create site like youtube

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, video-processing

I'm new to video rendering in web. So I'd like to ask which information resources should I read before starting development? Back-end technologies are: ASP.NET MVC, Azure.

The main question is: what is the best way to host videos? For example I could keep them right in site file system. Is it good/bad?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are on the MS stack. I'd suggest:

Azure media services.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/media-services/

It supports the multi-bit streaming and encoding of the videos and a number of other things.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Nice suggestion.